# Can a function be differentiable but not strongly differentiable (Knuth)?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, smooth-functions

Donald Knuth defined $f$ is *strongly differentiable at* $x$ if $$f(x+\epsilon) = f(x) + \epsilon f'(x) + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$.

What differentiable functions are *not* strongly differentiable? Clearly any analytic function is strongly differentiable by Taylor's Theorem with Remainder.  But even the [non-analytic smooth functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) would seem to have remainders that are subquadratic, making them strongly differentiable.  It would seem to me that to not be strongly differentiable requires a remainder that is supraquadratic but sublinear.

What is an example of a non strongly differentiable function? What is the remainder of the Taylor series? Can the remainder of a smooth function be supraquadratic?

Or perhaps the only examples are non smooth functions that still have a single derivative, perhaps constructable via integration?

Comment: Do you mean $ f ( x + \epsilon ) = f ( x ) + \epsilon f ' ( x ) + \mathcal O ( \epsilon ^ 2 ) $?

Comment: @TobyBartels Yes, thank you, fixed.

Comment: take $f(x) = |x|^{3/2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that smooth functions won't help here; in fact [any continuously differentiable function is strongly differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950247/show-that-a-function-is-strongly-differentiable-if-it-is-continuously-differenti) (I think that this is an equivalent notion).

For things like this, I like functions of the form $$ f ( x ) = \cases { x ^ n \sin ( 1 / x ) & $ x \ne 0 $ \\ 0 & $ x = 0 $. } $$  If $ n \leq 1 $, then this isn't even differentiable at $ 0 $.  If $ 1 < n < 2 $, then it's differentiable but not strongly differentiable.  If $ n = 2 $, then it's strongly differentiable but not continuously differentiable.  And if $ n > 2 $, then it's continuously differentiable.

Notice that because $ f ( 0 ) $ and $ f ' ( 0 ) $ are both $ 0 $, the remainder at $ 0 $ is $ f ( \epsilon ) = \epsilon ^ n \sin ( 1 / \epsilon ) $, so wanting this to be supraquadratic but sublinear is exactly asking for $ 1 < n < 2 $.

Comment: Neat.  Can this happen on an interval (not just an isolated point)?

Comment: @SRobertJames :  No, because if a function is differentiable on an interval, then it must be continuously differentiable on a dense subset of that interval.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be for a characterization of how often a derivative must be continuous.  (Since strong differentiability is weaker than continuous differentiability, that may have to happen even more often; I don't know any results about that.)